# Bound on a sum of divisor function

Tags: number-theory

I am currently reading a math paper in which the author writes :
$$\sum_{l\mid n}l\sigma_1(l)\ll n^2\sigma_{-1}(n)$$
Where the function $\sigma_k$ is defined by $\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d^k$ and does not give any detail for the proof. I have tried to do it by myself and show $\sum_{l\mid n}l\sigma_1(l)\ll n\sigma_1(n)$ but did not succeed.

Does anyone have an idea on how to prove this ? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Since both sides are multiplicative functions of $n$, a standard approach is to check the inequality when $n$ is a prime power. Can you prove that $\sum_{d\mid p^r} d\sigma_1(d) \le f(p) (p^r)^2 \sigma_{-1}(p^r)$, where $\prod_p f(p)$ converges?

Comment: After some calculation I got $f(p)=\frac{p^2}{p^2-1}$ hence $\prod_pf(p)$ converges and I can conclude, thanks a lot !